# How to do pandas column selection while getting code completion?

Tags: python, pandas

When working with pandas, I often use name based column indexing. E.g:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"abc":[1,2], "bde":[3,4], "mde":[3,4]})
df[["mde","bde"]]
```

As I have longer column names it because easy for me to create a typo in the column names since they are strings and no code completion. It'd be great if I could do something like:

```
df.SelectColumnsByObjectAttributeNotString([df.mde, df.bde])
```

Comment: It would be helpful if  you give a concrete example of a column with two values or something, and what you expect it to become.

Comment: There's [to_string](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) in pandas. I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for though: is it a function that will turn the content of the columns into strings or something else?

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is wildly open to interpretation. Please provide a _useful_ [mcve], thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and even more so for the patience. I'll ask more specific questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `name` attribute.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2], "b":[3,4]})
columns = [df.a.name, df.b.name]
columns
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Ridiculous as the question may be, I really think this is the right answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist really took a while to understand what OP means.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for:

```
df.columns.values.tolist()
```